# Should I include "a" after "conocemos"?

Tags: verbos, preposiciones

Which would be correct?

> 1. Nosotros conocemos a los padres de nuestros amigos.
> 2. Nosotros conocemos los padres de nuestros amigos.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, "a" should always be included when talking about knowing people.

It is not used with objects, though:

> Nosotros conocemos el lugar

Answer (score 2):

Yes. When the direct object is a person, or several, you use "a" before the object.